# Barycentric interpolation equivalent for irregular hexahedra

Tags: finite-element, interpolation, mesh

I have a mesh with irregular hexaedra and I need a fast way to interpolate values at points inside these cells. I know that trilinear interpolation does not work well for large skews. Barycentric coordinates work for tetrahedrons. Is there any equivalent method for hexaedra, which is really efficient, possibly parallelization-friendly?

Comment: No. They can be random as well.

Comment: I don't know what rectangular prisms are (or 4-sided prisms as in the title). Are you talking about a hexahedron?

Comment: yes! I couldn't recall the name.

Comment: the google books preview of TJ Chung's CFD book looks useful: https://books.google.com/books?id=Cq6tqmMVJREC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=%22irregular+hexahedron%22&source=bl&ots=He227cAgwq&sig=OXmO9fht1__r6QOE6B00oWxvFuA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicyvfUi7DWAhWE64MKHT4oAf0Q6AEITjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22irregular%20hexahedron%22&f=false

Answer (score 5):

A hexahedron with straight edges is the image of the unit cube under a trilinear mapping. So, if you have values on the eight vertices of a hexahedron, and you are asking to interpolate between them to a point $x$ somewhere inside the hexahedron, then the correct approach is as follows:

- Invert the trilinear mapping to find the corresponding point $\hat x = \Phi^{-1}(x)$ on the reference cell.
- Use the trilinear shape functions on the reference cell to evaluate at $\hat x$ to obtain the interpolated value of your function based on the values at the vertices.

The second step is easy. The first requires inverting the mapping $\Phi$, which in general requires a nonlinear Newton iteration because it is a nonlinear, polynomial you are inverting.